# Retain partial view information on page refresh in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, partial-views

A page has list of buttons on its left side menu. Initially page is rendered with this left side menu and a partial view on the main view. When a user clicks on one of the left side menu buttons, a relevant partial view is rendered in the container.

This idea is described here in this diagram:

[image]

Every partial view in turn has pagination on it. Suppose user is on page 4 of partial view 2 and refreshes the page, it goes back to the landing page.

I need to figure out how to store partial view information before page refreshes as well as its page number information for user to land to the same UI when page is refreshed.

This code is used initially to set the parent view:

```
public ActionResult ShopOnline()
{ 
    var list = db.Items.Include(i => i.Brand).Include(i => i.Category).ToList();
    var Cats = db.Categories.OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList();
    var SubCats = db.SubCategories.OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList();
    var FurtherSubCats = db.FurtherSubCategories.OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList();

    Dictionary<string, int> cattot = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    for (int j = 0; j < Cats.Count; j++)
    {
        var catName = Cats[j].Name.ToString();
        var result = db.Items.Count(x => x.Category.Name == catName);
        cattot.Add(Cats[j].Name, result);
    }
    Dictionary<string, int> SubCategoriesWithTotal = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    for (int i = 0; i < SubCats.Count; i++)
    {
        var SubCategoryName = SubCats[i].Name.ToString();
        var SubCategoryTotal = db.Items.Count(x => x.SubCategoryName == SubCategoryName);
        SubCategoriesWithTotal.Add(SubCats[i].Name, SubCategoryTotal);
    }
    Dictionary<string, int> FurtherSubCatsWithTotal = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    for (int k = 0; k < FurtherSubCats.Count; k++)
    {
        var FurtherSubCategoryName = FurtherSubCats[k].Name.ToString();
        var SubCategoryTotal = db.Items.Count(x => x.FurtherCategoryName == FurtherSubCategoryName);
        FurtherSubCatsWithTotal.Add(FurtherSubCats[k].Name, SubCategoryTotal);
    }
    var vm = new ShopOnlineVM
        {
            ListOfItems = list,
            SubCategories = SubCats,
            FurtherSubCategories = FurtherSubCats,
            CategoryNames = cattot,
            SubCategoryNames = SubCategoriesWithTotal,
            FurtherSubCatsNames = FurtherSubCatsWithTotal
        };
    return View(vm);
}
```

Page resulted from this code has a left side menu list. So when user clicks on one of its items, a partial view relevant to that is set within this parent view. Code for that is:

```
using PagedList;
public ActionResult GetCategoryItems(string categoryName, int? page)
    {
        var itemList = db.Items.Where(x => x.CategoryName == categoryName).ToList().ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 30); 
        return PartialView("_categoryDetails", itemList);
    }
```

**Partial View**

```
@using PagedList;
@using PagedList.Mvc;
@model IPagedList<OnlineStore.Models.Item>    
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>    
<div id="itemsInACategory">
    <div id="wrapper-Details" class="wrapper">
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        { //...items are rendered }
    </div>
    @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("GetCategoryItems", new { page, categoryName = Model.First().CategoryName }), PagedListRenderOptions.EnableUnobtrusiveAjaxReplacing(new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "GET", UpdateTargetId = "itemsInACategory" }))
</div>
```

This repeats for every left side menu item i.e., clicking an item renders relevant partial view.

What I need is suppose user has clicked left side menu item 6 to render PartialView number 6 and PartialView number 6 has 10 pages and user is on page 7, and refreshes the page, right now it is taking user back to Parent page (landing page) obviously because that *is* the very page user is refreshing which has no information about the rendered partial view within its URL.

I'm not sure how to make sure user lands on the very relevant partial view after refresh button is clicked.

I applied this existing logic because of the left-side menu items (categories). These categories have sub-categories which have further-sub-categories and when user initially clicks on the category item, all categories list items slide to the left side (artificially disappear) and sub-categories relevant to that categories slide in and same repeats for every sub-category click to show further-sub-category. All this happens on the left side and on the right (main) section of the page, relevant PartialView is rendering.

Now if I change the logic to store information in the URL about the category, sub-category or further-sub-category name and page number and route to another action and hence a new page(view), I'm not sure how to slide relevant left side menu showing the exact point of view (i.e., category, sub-category - or further-sub-category).

A working example what I need to achieve is here (https://shop.coles.com.au/a/a-national/everything/browse1)

Comment: Can you show us some code mainly if you use client paging or server paging - solutions can differ

Comment: @Pribina - I've updated code above. Please let me know if you need anything more. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Base on code you can use server session to save this data. but you need to take care when should it be cleared if you expect it.

I didnt run it but basically you save requested page in session. otherwise load it from session or choose default. Session stores it by partial page key.

controller code

```
     private Dictionary<string, int> SavedPaging
    {
        get
        {
            var saved = (Dictionary<string, int>)Session[nameof(SavedPaging)];
            if (saved is null)
            {
                Session[nameof(SavedPaging)] = saved = new Dictionary<string, int>();
            }

            return saved;
        }
        set { Session[nameof(SavedPaging)] = value; }
    }

    public ActionResult GetCategoryItems(string categoryName, int? page)
    {
        const string pageKey = nameof(GetCategoryItems);
        if (!page.HasValue && SavedPaging.ContainsKey(pageKey))
        {
            var savedPage = SavedPaging[pageKey];
            page = savedPage;
        }
        else if(page.HasValue && !SavedPaging.ContainsKey(pageKey))
        {
            SavedPaging.Add(pageKey,page.Value);
        }
        else if(page.HasValue && SavedPaging.ContainsKey(pageKey))
        {
            SavedPaging[pageKey] = page.Value;
        }

        var itemList = db.Items.Where(x => x.CategoryName == categoryName).ToList().ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 30);
        return PartialView("_categoryDetails", itemList);
    }
```

Comment: Still rendering landing page when refresh page is pressed after applying above code.

Comment: sorry i forgot that way property SavedPaging dictionary is not saved. i updated code

Comment: `$exception{"Sequence contains no elements"} System.InvalidOperationException`
on line 
`@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("GetCategoryItems", new { page, categoryName = Model.First().CategoryName }), PagedListRenderOptions.EnableUnobtrusiveAjaxReplacing(new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "GET", UpdateTargetId = "itemsInACategory" }))` in the PartialView

Comment: When I click on a menu button, it rendered relevant partial view. I went to its page 3 and pressed refresh button. It rendered the landed page. I clicked on the menu button again and it threw above `exception`.

Comment: If you wanna take up TeamViewer access to check its behavior, please feel free to let me know. Thanks

Comment: do you use different actions for different partal views or its same partial view with different data? 

if its same partial view then i understood you wrong and we need to update 'pageKey ' to 'categoryName'

Comment: No I'm using different actions for different partial views.

Comment: that exception means you have no elements in page model and its probably connected to that categoryName(which is not stored in session)

Comment: It is a Partial View .. and not a normal parent view. Key it is saving is the method name (`GetCategoryItems`) when the partial view name is (for example - `_categoryDetails`).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193452/discussion-between-pribina-and-netjedovic).

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't able to fix this issue and I cannot reply in the chat room your created for some reason so replying here. Please message me when you're around if you're still willing to help me so we can discuss things further. Thank you.

Comment: please update question to reflect your changes, so i can update answer. this way  oth of us might receive negative feedback